# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'overlay.addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a big project and I got an error.

It's a popup window.

I added it inside my app js file.

Before I added, everything went well, but now I got an error.

If anyone knows what my problem is, please let me know.

It should look like this: [image]

This is my code, I copied it from an HTML, CSS, and JS tutorial:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Popup.styles.css";

function Popup() {
    
    const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')
    const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
    const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

    openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
        openModal(modal)
    })
    })

    overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active')
    modals.forEach(modal => {
        closeModal(modal)
    })
    })

    closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const modal = button.closest('.modal')
        closeModal(modal)
    })
    })

    function openModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return
    modal.classList.add('active')
    overlay.classList.add('active')
    }

    function closeModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return
    modal.classList.remove('active')
    overlay.classList.remove('active')
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button data-modal-target="#modal">Open Modal</button>
            <div class="modal" id="modal">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="title">Example Modal</div>
                    <button data-close-button class="close-button">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Lorem ipsum...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Popup
```

And this is the error I got:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'overlay.addEventListener')
Popup
src/Popup.js:17
  14 | })
  15 | })
  16 | 
> 17 | overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
     | ^  18 | const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active')
  19 | modals.forEach(modal => {
  20 |     closeModal(modal)
```

Please answer, you won't hurt my feelings.

Thank you in advance!

Emiel

Comment: do you have `overlay` id element in your app ?

Comment: and using the `querySelector`s defeats the purpose of using React

Comment: you are missing an element with `overlay` ID inside your HTML, that's why it doesn't work

Comment: I understand thanks!